# Mapbox GL JS - remove cluster effect on mbtiles

Tags: cluster-computing, mapbox-gl-js, points, mbtiles

I am currently working with a large file of points that I want to filter according to properties and bounding box.

When I add this layer to my map using a geojson file, I can manage the cluster effect using property as mentioned in [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson-clusteR) but the file is quite large to load in the browser.
So I think it is better to go through a mbtiles file. I use tippecanoe for the conversion goejson to mbtiles

But, when I add this mbtiles file as a source there is a cluster-effect that I want to remove.

I am just asking how to remove the cluster-effect using mbtiles? Is it possible? 
I cannot find this in the API documentation, but it's possible I missed it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section

> Dropping a fixed fraction of features by zoom level

says that default drop rate is 2.5, set it to 1 before generating mbtiles.

`--drop-rate=1`